# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

After request `http://localhost:8080/example/rest/hello/message` i got the error "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found". What is the problem? I use Tomcat 8. Thanks in advance.

App.java:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class App extends Application{
}
```

Service.java

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Service {

@GET
@Path("/message")
public String getMessage() {

    String message = "Welcome";
    return message;

   }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

...........................................................................

Comment: As I see your path to server is not including `example` then try: `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello/message`

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: Can you show me the `web.xml` file

Comment: It is in the description.

Comment: Change this line `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` to `@ApplicationPath("rest")` and try with your previous path in case of `example` is your project name.

Comment: The result is the same.